# How to generate multiple, non-independent samples from a multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: correlation, sampling, multivariate-distribution

Suppose I have a multivariate normal (MVN) distribution:

$$\textbf{X} \sim MVN({\mu},\Sigma)$$

where $\Sigma \neq \sigma^2\textbf{I}$ i.e. the RVs within $\textbf{X}$ have some correlation structure.

It is straightforward to generate multiple independent samples from this distribution using Cholesky decomposition etc.

It is also straightforward to sample $X_1 = [x_1, \dots, x_m]$ given $X_2 = [x_{m+1},\dots,x_{n}]$  where $\textbf{X} = [X_1, X_2]$, given the conditional distribution properties of MVN.

However I want to generate *non-independent* samples from the MVN distribution.. In particular I generate one central sample $\textbf{x}^{(1)}$, then generate $\textbf{x}^{(2)},...$ from the same MVN but which are *correlated* with $\textbf{x}^{(1)}$.

Methods considered:

1) A simple method would be to sample each element $x_i^{(2)}$ of $\textbf{x}^{(2)}$ separately as a conditional normal distribution $x_i^{(2)}$ given $x_i^{(1)}$ with some $\rho$ specified as desired degree of correlation, as if they formed their own bivariate distribution:

$$x_i^{(2)}|x_i^{(1)} \sim N\Big(\mu_i + \rho \frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_i}(x_i^{(1)} - \mu_i), (1-\rho^2)\sigma_i^{2}\Big) \equiv  N\Big((1-\rho)\mu_i + \rho x_i^{(1)},(1-\rho^2)\sigma_i^{2}\Big)$$

But this does not factor in the correlation structure from the MVN.

2) Another method would be a single iteration of Gibbs sampling over some partitioning of the RVs e.g. iteratively resample between:

$$X_1 | X_2, \qquad \qquad X_2 | X_1$$

but this does not offer a natural $\rho$ to control degree of correlation.

(Alternatively each $x_i$ element could be sampled conditional on all of the others...?)

3) A crude way would be to generate a large number of samples then define a distance function between the samples, and choose among the low-distance samples generated. The distance threshold and number of samples offers a crude way to control degree of correlation.

Is there a rigorous way to generate non-independent samples according to some desired correlation $\rho$ from the MVN?

**EDIT:**

Suggestion from comments below.... Given $\textbf{x}^{(1)}$ sampled from $MVN_n(\mu,\Sigma)$, we can define the next sample $\textbf{x}^{(2)}$ as part of a jointly MVN distribution as follows:

$$\textbf{x}' = \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{x}^{(1)} \\ \textbf{x}^{(2)}\end{bmatrix} \sim MVN_{2n} (\mu', \Sigma')$$

where

$$\mu' = \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ \mu \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Sigma' = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma & \rho \Sigma \\ \rho \Sigma & \Sigma \end{bmatrix}$$

and $\rho \in [-1,1]$ controls the degree of correlation between $\textbf{x}^{(1)}, \textbf{x}^{(2)}$. Then the standard properties of MVN re. conditional distribution can be used to define the distribution of $\textbf{x}^{(2)} | \textbf{x}^{(1)}$:

$$\textbf{x}^{(2)} | \textbf{x}^{(1)} \sim MVN(\mu + (\rho \Sigma) (\Sigma)^{-1} (\textbf{x}^{(1)} - \mu),\Sigma - (\rho \Sigma) (\Sigma)^{-1} (\rho \Sigma))$$

$$ \equiv MVN(\mu + \rho (\textbf{x}^{(1)} - \mu),(1-\rho^2)\Sigma )$$

This distribution can be sampled from to get another sample $x^{(2)}$ which is from the same MVN distribution but correlated with the first sample, to degree $\rho$.

Does this work?

Comment: Your question is underspecified. 1. Presumably you want them to be *jointly* normal, is that right? (there many other possibilities). 2. You have two vectors that you say you want to be correlated, but their cross-covariance $\Sigma_{12}$ is a matrix (a submatrix of their joint covariance matrix). So the correlation between the vectors is not specified by a single value ($\rho$) but rather by an $n\times n$ matrix, unless you mean that only corresponding elements of the two vectors are correlated, all at the same correlation, with every other correlation $\text{corr}(X_{1i},X_{2j})$ being $0$.

Comment: 1. I guess they are jointly normal... they both need to be sampled from the same MVN$_n$ with $n$ elements and covariance $\Sigma$ but be correlated i.e. not independent.  2. I guess you are suggesting that $x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}$, both samples from the same MVN$_n$, could be considered a single sample from a larger MVN$_{2n}$ which has some covariance $\Sigma'$ where $\Sigma_{11}' = \Sigma_{22}' = \Sigma$ defines correlation within samples, and $\Sigma_{12}'$ encodes the correlation between samples $x_{(1)}, x_{(2)}$?

Comment: in relation to 2: Indeed, if you want them to be jointly normal, that's exactly the case. If you only wanted correlation between corresponding elements of each vector, $\Sigma_{12}$ would be diagonal.

Comment: happy to give you the answer if you post it...!

Comment: it looks like there's a faster approach than the general one for your particular problem (assuming I understand it correctly). If the dimension is large it may make a fairly large difference. In particular, a Cholesky decomposition of the common $\Sigma$ can be used to obtain a Cholesky decomposition of the larger matrix. I'll try to post on it later.